# PaxExam tests configured with wrappedBundle()

Tags: apache-karaf, wiremock, pax-exam

For the configuration in PaxExam (version 4) we're using `wrappedBundle()` as you can see here:

```
wrappedBundle(mavenBundle().groupId("com.github.tomakehurst").artifactId("wiremock-jre8").versionAsInProject()),
```

Because we want to create an OSGi bundle out of an ordinary jar.

Then in order the wrap mechanism can be used we have to install the *wrap* feature:

```
features(karafStandardRepo, "wrap"),
```

The problem is when it comes to install `wrappedBundle()` the wrap feature is not yet there. How can I assure in the PaxExam configuration `wrappedBundle()` is executed only after the *wrap* feature is there and ready for use? The Karaf distribution we are using in this test is version 4.0.7.

Thanks for help,
Kladderradatsch

Comment: On the following page it was mentioned that in a feature xml you should declare the _wrap_ feature with an attribute `prerequisite` but for the test I actually don't have a feature xml file. So how can I declare this in the scope of the PaxExam API?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ops4j/Yx-5AF0Mquo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed we had to wrap the WireMock bundle generation by the PaxUrl Wrap mechanism into a separate feature file:

```
<features name="wiremock-${project.version}" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0">
    <feature name="wiremock" version="${project.version}">
        <feature prerequisite="true">wrap</feature>
        <bundle>
            wrap:mvn:com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-jre8-standalone/2.21.0$Bundle-ClassPath=.
        </bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

Very important is here to configure the XML namespace properly, namely to address version **v1.4.0** otherwise `prerequisite` is of no use. A further pitfall I stepped in before was not taking the standalone version of WireMock.

Then in the PaxExam configuration I have just installed the feature:

```
features(maven().groupId("com.company.wiremock").artifactId("wiremock-feature").type("xml").classifier("features").version("1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"), "wiremock"),
```

When it comes to initialize the WireMockServer in your tests, in order the resources in the new generated WireMock-Bundle can be loaded via `ClassLoader.getResource()` (internal stuff of that library), you have to do this here in your test otherwise the Bundle-Classloader of that WireMock-Bundle is not used:

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        ClassLoader savedClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(WireMockClassRule.class.getClassLoader());
            wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().dynamicPort());
            wireMockServer.start();
        } finally {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(savedClassLoader);
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void end() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }
```

You could put this in a JUnit `@ClassRule` for encapsulation.